# Spring Security + Spring MVC how to integrate them properlly?

Tags: spring, design-patterns, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a working project with both frameworks doing fine

My problem is how to architect it.

I have set 3 Roles ( Admin, Operator, User), and one folder for each of them. like thid

```
WebContent
     |___admin
     |___user
     |___operator
     |___WEB-INF
         |__jsp
```

in admin,user, and operator are those roles only jsps
in jsp are all public jsps.

Is this the right way to do it ?
because when I create my viewResolver it only points to Web-Inf->jsp... So I am having trouble to make my requests land on those folders.

I want to be able to put a .jsp in a folder so it would automatically be assigned to a Role.
But I would like to be able to reuse the JSPs too.

Should I create another view resolver to each of those folders ? 
Should they all be inside the WEB-INF folder ?
What is the best (more used and simple) way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the user role folders into WEB-INF and used redirect... now it's working.